# Scheduling a JDBC Inbound channel Adaptor

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to run the JDBC Inbound channel Adaptor to run specific hours in a day however, when it is running it needs to poll every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop and start the adapter whenever you want; either programmatically or using a [control bus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus).

Comment: thanks @Gary-russell, How can I do that programmatically when my spring integration configuration is xml based?

Comment: If your adapter has an id `myJdbcInbound`, `@Autowired`  `SourcePollingChannelAdapter myJdbcInbound` (or add a `@Qualifier` if you want to use a different field name); then call `stop()/start()` as needed. If you are not using auto wiring, use setter or constructor injection of the SPCA with `ref="myJdbcInbound"`. Set `autoStartup` to `false` to prevent Spring from starting it when the context is initialized.